# How to make exoplayer play the video from Drive

Tags: android, url, video, exoplayer

Currently, I am trying to play a video from the web. I tried many ways to play a video from the web but nothing worked. I first used videoView and I was always saying that the video file can not be played. The link doesn't really have to be from Drive or to use the method I use right now. I just need to make it work.

Here is what the code looks like right now:

```
String url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CRJ8tL-DyjD0Nwd7ezkboGm6570zMf4C/view?usp=sharing";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starter_yoga);

    findViewById(R.id.backY).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        onBackPressed();

    });

    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.SY);

    playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url);
    simpleExoPlayer.addMediaItem(mediaItem);

    simpleExoPlayer.prepare();
    simpleExoPlayer.play();

}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
Error:

```
   2021-08-30 15:37:32.662 4582-6879/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory 
 (directory doesn't exist?).
   2021-08-30 15:37:35.676 4130-4254/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl 
 is 
  netid 0
    2021-08-30 15:37:35.708 4130-4260/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
   2021-08-30 15:37:35.778 4164-4184/? E/HYPER-HAL: [Request.cpp]acquire(): Request:: id : 
   10586920, No Resource to set
   2021-08-30 15:37:36.179 4219-4242/? E/BufferQueueProducer: 
  [com.example.diligent/com.diligent_app.diligent.yoga.Yoga$_20925#0](id:107b0000491d,api:0,p:-1,c:4219) disconnect: not connected 

  2021-08-30 15:37:36.526 3933-3933/? E/vold: getUsedF2fsFileNode -> Cannot Get Used FileNode Number (errno=25 Inappropriate ioctl for device)
2021-08-30 15:37:36.718 20925-23908/com.example.diligent E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
  com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:624)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:594)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
 Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1025)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:409)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the URL format like this:

```
String videoURL = "https://drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=1hMzertAC6ap31Xup6_B0fJP-fbZP7GFX&export=download";
```

Where `1hMzertAC6ap31Xup6_B0fJP-fbZP7GFX` is your video ID.

Comment: This works for me too! you can also drop the "/u/1" from the url.
Check out my link for a sus shaggy song
`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1s6iRgt0WLRyK17isK_ALr9LXm48HByMe&export=download`

Answer (score 1):

From the error, the problem is likely that the device does not support the video encoding.

From ffprobe (https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html):

```js
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/y_v_starter_yoga.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:06:00.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 860 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1080x2260 [SAR 1:1 DAR 54:113], 839 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 14 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

You can see it is using 'High' Profile which many Android devices will not support - see here for the standard media support:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

If you can re encode it using baseline profile you can verify this is the issue.

If you want to see working examples of ExoPlayer playing web video, ExoPlayer's own sample player includes these. You can also edit the samples JSON Media list to add in your own video links and test them directly with the ExoPlayer sample player.

Comment: From what I discovered, the problem is not the code, but the link. I tried different links from already made players and some work some not. Do you know any website from where I can make one or a way to make mine work.? I tried almost everything I saw and nothing worked.

Comment: @DiligentPD ffmpeg is probably the most common tool to transcode video - see an example here showing how to set the profile level: https://superuser.com/a/564007